# Some objects created with PerWebRequest are not garbage collected at the end of web request

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, castle-windsor, perwebrequest

Given

```
public class a : IDisposable
{
    public static int counter;

    public a()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    ~a()
    {
        counter--;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

With registration:

```
application_container = new WindsorContainer( );
application_container.Register( Component.For<a>( ).ImplementedBy<a>( ).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest );
```

Proper stuff in web.config:

```
       <add name="PerRequestLifestyle"
type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule,
Castle.MicroKernel"/>
```

Using version of Castle built from SVN.
With web page code:

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           GC.Collect( 2 );
           var a = Global.application_container.Resolve<Global.a>();
           Response.Write( Global.a.counter.ToString() );
       }
   }
```

I get that ~a() is not called and RedGate profiler shows that a is not
being collected, the reference to it stuck in
AllComponentsReleasePolicy.instance2burden.

---

I am not the first one to encounter this problem

http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/bd287dd66b3a9d64/f48d740621508c64?lnk=gst&q=PerWebrequest#f48d740621508c64

Comment: discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/213cfee9df8b692e

Answer (score 1):

We found a similar issue in 2.1, seems to have been fixed along the way, upgrading should fix it.